# reducing decimal places in a table

Tags: list-manipulation

How can I reduce the number of decimal places within a table to let's say two digits? The default setting is 6 decimal places. this is the mathematcia code:

```
tabelle = Table[-β k^ϵA /. k -> 1.5, {β, 0, 1, 0.25}, {ϵA, -0.5, 1, 0.5}]; 
Prepend[tabelle, {"ϵA=-0.5", "ϵA=0", "ϵA=0.5", "ϵA=1"}] // TableForm
```

Comment: Look up `Round[]`.

Comment: Or  `NumberForm`...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: NumberForm works, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have the numbers align in `TableForm` you can use `PaddedForm` as it leave space for the negative sign.  This needs to be `Map`ped onto the entries in the list.

```
Prepend[Map[PaddedForm[#, {3, 2}] &, tabelle, {2}], 
   {"\[Epsilon]A=-0.5", "\[Epsilon]A=0", "\[Epsilon]A=0.5", "\[Epsilon]A=1"}] // TableForm
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks a lot!

Comment: Here is the same functionality built into a `TableForm` command: `tblFm2Dgt[x_List,opt :OptionsPattern[]] /;Length@Dimensions@x >1 :=TableForm[Map[PaddedForm[#,{3,2}]&, x, {2}], opt]`, which would let one do something like: `tblFm2Dgt[tabelle,TableHeadings -> {None, {"eA=-0.5", "eA=0","eA=0.5", "eA=1"}}]`